# How to add domain group as member of another domain group with command line

Tags: windows

I am creating a script but i have a doubt.

I need add a domain group as member of another domain group. 
I'm using dsmod but is not working.

tnx

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Powershell if possible. You should be able to use the [Add-AdGroupMember](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps) command.

```
$src = Get-AdGroup "Finance"
$dest = Get-AdGroup "Sales"
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $dest -Members $src
```